# React Native TouchableHighlight renders empty

Tags: react-native

The following component does not display anything and no error or warning gets fired. Any idea why?

```
class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableHighlight
          onPress={...}
          style={styles.main}
          >
          <Text>
            Some text
          </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that the problem is the style property passed to the TouchableHighlight component. Moving the style prop to the View component fixes the issue.